# Android Application crashed when share debug APK from output folder

Tags: android, crash, android-sharing

I am working on one application that have only one screen barcode scanning and I am achieve this with zxing Library. But my problem is if I am install app with android studio it is working fine but if I share this apk from output folder with Bluetooth, Email, Xender, etc.. Application is install but when I open the app it will crash and Exception is NoClassFoundException.

Here is Logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    Process: com.jenex.cartracking, PID: 31223                                                                       

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
 ComponentInfo{com.jenex.cartracking/com.jenex.cartracking.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.jenex.cartracking.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jenex.cartracking-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3029)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.jenex.cartracking.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jenex.cartracking-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jenex.cartracking.MainActivity
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                        ... 13 more
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Please post your entire LogCat. That helps anyone to give a proper solution.

Comment: The same problem. I used to share that apk with testers too. For test, I even created empty clean project with android studio, start it from studio, and it works fine on the phone. But if I put apk from 'output' folder, apk installs well, but crashes on start. Now searching for reasons and solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You have to clean build before share the app and make a debug build.

Follow this simple steps,

> 1. Goto Build -> Clean Project
> 2. Goto Build -> Build Apk

This will generate build Apk. Share this Apk.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried it but not solved.Please look at my Logcat

Comment: Have you set **multiDexEnabled true** in defaultConfig of build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have the same problem. Such an exception happens now with any project, even with empty and clean just created. I used to share myproject_debug.apk with testers, but now it crashes on start up. Maybe it started after some update of Android Studio or platform-tools, I'm not sure.

So, I found some work around that work for me

Before copy project-debug.apk from output folder:

- go to menu in Android Studio and open menu 'Build'
- click 'Build APK'

After successful build I copy myproject-debug.apk from output folder and it works well.